# How to Center Image/CreateCapture on p5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, p5.js

I've set up a split-screen canvas, currently with only one canvas on the left side of the screen. I want to display my webcam output on the left-hand side, and my current solution is to match the dimensions of the canvas with the webcam output. However, although this fits the canvas it also shrinks the width dimension of the output. I was wondering if there's any way I can map the capture directly to the canvas rather than have to match the dimensions and the positions on the screen. I've tried looking for the available functions for a createCapture object but there doesn't seem to be any useful functions. Any help would be appreciated. I have shown my code below:

```py
function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth / 2, windowHeight);
    webcam = createCapture(VIDEO, function(stream) {
        recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {});
    });
    webcam.size(windowWidth / 2, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
    clear();
    image(webcam, 0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

Comment: Your long description never mentions "center" yet the premise of your question is about centering and image. So is your question about sizes and shapes or about centering?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am trying to map a video onto the canvas on the left side of the screen, so that it is centered within that canvas, and the width of the capture is not changed (the overflowing width gets cut off on both sides).